# Uncaught Reference Error - $ is not defined + JQuery not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have been struggling to understand the errors on this page. Can someone help me and show me how to fix this page.

https://www.caternow.com.au/richmond-3121-caterers/Fabulous-Catering

It doesn't load properly and gives following error.

- Uncaught Reference Error - $ is not defined
- Uncaught Reference Error - JQuery is not defined

While the same code and same css/js works fine at below test site.

http://cater2.tecexperts.com/richmond-3121-caterers/Fabulous-Catering

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
DK

Comment: You've included a lot of jQuery plugins, but not jQuery itself. That's your issue

Comment: You are loading jquery plugins but not jquery itself

Comment: You are missing a lot of code on the first site you referenced. You're even missing the `html`, `head` and `body` tags

Comment: Looks like something happened to your live site. Lots of code was nuked.

Comment: Thanks a lot. it helps

Answer (score 2):

First of all don't load `typehead` and `typehade.min` together.

Second - you are not loading `jQuery` anywhere. Load it before any other scripts.

Comment: Thanks a lot. it helps

Answer (score 2):

On the test site you have a script tag in the html:

```
<script src="http://cater2.tecexperts.com/media/front/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

This loads the jQuery library, but the first page you linked doesn't contain this script tag. (there may be other possible missing tags too)

Comment: Thanks a lot. it helps

Answer (score 1):

include this on the top of your page

```html
<script src="http://cater2.tecexperts.com/media/front/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: and it missed the bootstrap includes too, check those too

Comment: Thanks a lot. it helps

Comment: always ready to help :-)